# change class when scroll in the last 200px of the page. Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have two functions & One Button that have to change of class when getting to the last `200px` of the page scroll.

**HTML**

```
  <div class=".GoToBottom">[click me to Go]</div>
```

**SCROLL TO BOTTOM** (works every 500px)

```
$('.GoToBottom').on("click",function () {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=500px'}, 800);
  });
```

**SCROLL TO TOP** (works every 500px)

```
$('.GoToTop').on("click",function () {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '-=500px'}, 800);
  });
```

So, Once the scroll gets into the last `200px` of the bottom, I want to change the class of the `div element` to make it go upwards.

I tried this, but doesnt work

```
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()-200) {
        alert("bottom!");
              //$('.Go').toggleClass("GoToBottom GoToTop");   
         }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xoz3b1dc/9/ I cant make the change work.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for toggling the class has the wrong comparison operator. You are using `==` which work for that exact pixel (when user is exactly 200 pixels from the bottom). You need to check if it is equal OR greater than the value with `>=`:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()-200) {
    alert("bottom!");
    //$('.Go').toggleClass("GoToBottom GoToTop");   
}
```

Comment: Ok. thank you. please check out this fiddle I cant make it work. I'm checking now `>=`  https://jsfiddle.net/xoz3b1dc/26/

Comment: I added `$(window).scroll`, so it checks the scroll position when it changes, and not only once as it was before.